# calling a class function from another class function

Tags: php, oop

I'm new to programming. I have this going on:

I have Class A, which have many functions. One of those functions is functionX.

In functionX I need to make a call to functionY which belongs to another class: Class B.

So how do I acces to functionY from inside functionX?

I use Codeigniter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because 'good' is very ambiguous when it comes to technical texts. Some people learn by sifting through the most hardcore of manuals while others learn better by examples.

Comment: @NeilMasters - There are a variety of text books - so a good one is for your learning style

Comment: I agree with @EdHeal this is basic OO, a good book would explain it better than any of us could

Comment: @EdHeal unnecessary comment.

Comment: Just call `B::functionY();`

Comment: @meda - Would also explain static/non-static methods. Inheritance etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that depends. If that function is a static function or not.

First off you must include the file with the class...

```
include_once('file_with_myclass.php');
```

If it is static you can call it like this:

```
ClassName::myFunction()
```

If it is not, then you create an instance of the class and then call the function on that instance.

```
$obj = new ClassName();
$obj->myFunction();
```

As you can guess the function being static means you can call it without the need of creating an instance. That is useful for example if you have a class Math and want to define a function that takes to arguments to calculate the sum of them. It wouldn't really be useful to create an instance of Math to do that, so you can declare as static and use it that way.

Here's a link to the docs with further info

http://www.php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

Answer (score 1):

Try and experiment with this.

```
class ClassA {
    public function functionX() {
        $classB = new ClassB();
        echo $classB->functionY();
    }
}

class ClassB {
    public function functionY() {
        return "Stahp, no more OO, stahp!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Class function?  A static method?

If you have an instance (public) method, you just call $classB->functionY().

If you have a static method, you would call ClassB::functionY();

So:

```
class ClassA {
    public function functionX(){
       $classB = new ClassB();
       // echo 'foo';
       echo $classB->functionY();

       // echo 'bar';
       echo ClassB::functionYStatic();
    }
}

class ClassB {
    public $someVar;
    public static $someVar2 = 'bar';

    function __construct(){
      $this->someVar = 'foo';
    }
    public function functionY(){
       return $this->someVar;
    }
    public static function functionYStatic(){
       return self::$someVar2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If functionY is static you can call ClassB::functionY(). Else you must create instance of Class B first. Like:

```
$instance = ClassB;
$instance->functionY();
```

But maybe you mean something else?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your class has a dependency to another one:

```
<?php

class A
{
    public function x()
    {
        echo 'hello world';
    }
}

class B
{
    private $a;

    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;
    }

    public function y()
    {
        $this->a->x();
    }
}

$a = new A();
$b = new B($a);
$b->y();
```

Depending how your code looks like, if it makes sense, you can inject class A into y()

```
public function y(A $a)
{
    // your code with $a
}
```